# keptn get upstream repository not found error while creating project

Tags: git, repository, orchestration

I'm trying to work with Keptn but When i'm trying to create a keptn project with a git remote repository, i'm getting the error

```
The project could not be created: upstream repository not found.
```

First, the repo I've created is completely empty. And when i use the same repo with the same token key in a online `keptn` tutorial, it works there.

I follow all the instructions in `keptn` website but I don't understand where the problem come from.

Answer (score 0):

I found out it might be caused by one of these reasons :

- all the pods is not running
- the git repository is not entirely empty (even a Readme is not good)
- or simply the url you provided is wrong.

For me, it was the first option. Hope it will help someone else.